# Use Mathematica (or other method) to find zeros of function

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to find an analytical solution for the expression:

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{4\pi}\left[\left(2\pi-t\right)\left(2+\cos t\right)+3\sin t\right]-\frac{1}{2} = 0
\end{equation}

in the region $0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$ but have had no luck thus far. I have tried simply rearranging the expression, but cannot isolate or factorise the terms. I was looking for a substitution or transformation that might help, but have drawn a blank. I was looking for an analytical expression because a simple plot of the function in Mathematica shows the zero at around 2.5:

[image]

However, I have also tried the NSolve and Solve functions which fail to provide a solution. Any suggestions gratefully received.

Comment: One solution is adding a domain in `Solve` which gives you a result. Use `Solve[ EQ , t , Reals]`. (Version 13.2)

Comment: `FindRoot[-(1/2) + ((2 π - t) (2 + Cos[t]) + 3 Sin[t])/(    4 π) == 0, {t, 1}]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

eqn = 1/(4 Pi) ((2 Pi - t) (2 + Cos[t]) + 3 Sin[t]) - 1/2 == 0;
```

Include the constraint in the [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html). Then the exact solution is a [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) expression

```
sol = Solve[{eqn, 0 < t < 2 Pi}, t][[1]]
```

[image]

Verifying,

```
eqn /. sol // FullSimplify

(* True *)
```

Its approximate value is

```
sol // N

(* {t -> 2.50815} *)
```

Similarly with [`Reduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html),

```
Reduce[{eqn, 0 < t < 2 Pi}, t]
```

[image]

Or with [`NSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html)

```
NSolve[{eqn, 0 < t < 2 Pi}, t][[1]]

(* {t -> 2.50815} *)
```

Comment: Thank you Bob - really helpful. Am not quite sure why this has been closed and marked as a "simple mistake".  There is in fact only one zero of this function - so its not unreasonable to expect Mathemmatica to find it - or am I missing something?

Comment: There is only one zero in the real domain but without specifying the domain or specifying a real interval of interest, Mathematica assumes that you want solutions in the complex plane, and it says it doesn't know how to solve that problem. That should have suggested to you to refer to the documentation. The approaches above are "easily found in the documentation."